# Where can I get a schematic of the houdaille rotary shock absorber?

Tags: ford, vintage, shock-absorber

Rotary shock abosrbers were used in period cars examples are: Ford model A, also bugatti, and ferrari. Does this type of rotary shock absorber use silicone viscous fluid as a dampener or some spring mechanism in a rotary housing. Does anyone have a schematic of such a shock absorber, for viewing, or understanding the workings of such a rotary shock absorber?

Comment: Was silicone viscous fluid available during the productionntime of the Ford Model A? afaik these were friction dampers and are well described in many engineering texts, so a bit of a search is necessary.

Comment: Siloxanes were first characterised by Frederic Kipping in 1927, also the first production year of the Model A... one link : https://goo.gl/images/DoXXG5

Comment: yeah, so far as I know these are friction devices like clutches and brakes.

Comment: All the ones I have restored had a spring, piston and petroleum fluid or oil, I took them apart, cleaned and reassembled, most of them had worn out pistons so most fluids did not help dampen the suspension, an old man told me to fill them with STP oil additive, well that worked they now dampened the suspension.

Comment: They are also called Lever Arm shock absorbers....https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lever_arm_shock_absorber

Comment: There are tons of designs.......https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1619&bih=1251&ei=L1dDXIHDCOuCjwSXhJaIAw&q=+Lever+arm+shock+absorber&oq=+Lever+arm+shock+absorber&gs_l=img.12..0j0i5i30j0i8i30j0i24l4.1353.1353..2958...0.0..0.77.77.1......1....2j1..gws-wiz-img.....0.mv_ebCjUvqc

Comment: http://www.goldcoastmodela.com/Shocks/hhist.html